# Azure Devops branch security not saving

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to edit my branch security policies, but nothing ever seems to save. I've tried editing permissions, adding groups, removing groups and nothing seems to happen.

Is there supposed to be save button? This interface is new and appears not to be working.

*I am an admin on this Azure account.*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the above question you posted in comment, here is the answer for that:

The groups listed below are inbuilt groups. You will not be able to delete those inbuilt groups.

[image]

And if you would like to add any groups, you would need to first create that group in Project Settings and then come back to Branch Security and Add that group here :

Go to Project Settings --> Security --> Create Group

[image: Create Group]

Once you Create the group, go back to Repos --> Branches --> Branch Security --> Click on Add Group and search for the group you created earlier.

You should be able to delete the groups that you have created, But keep one thing in mind that if you delete a group that you created all the users in the group will loose permissions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a New UI and it is automatic save when you change the permissions.

Have you tried changing the selection in the dropdown and see if it works?

- Once you change the selection in dropdown there will be an indication that the value is changed.
- There is no Save Button in the new UI.
- The Green tick indicates that the value is changed.

Please take a look at the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: I see the green checks showing up and I believe those are working. However, I am unable to delete any of the groups and sometimes add them. They disappear and then I refresh and they're there again.

Comment: Posted another answer for the above question. Since it has lot of information to share, it might not fit in the comments section.